# Is there a good mono-spaced font for Devanagari script in the Terminal?

Tags: kde, gnome-terminal, fonts

All the terminal fonts I have tried result in inaccurate rendering of the Devanagari sript (and/or Roman script) in the Terminal

In the Devanagari script, a vowel binds itself to a preceding consonant. This type of vowel does not exist on its own. The dotted circle indicates that it requires a preceding consonant...
Here is an example of an as yet unattached vowel: [VOWEL SIGN O'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/94b/index.htm)

Proper font rendering  does the work of grafting the consonanat to the vowel, and should remove all visible signs of the dotted-circle....

...but I can't find a Terminal font which renders both the Roman script and Devanagari scripts satisfactorily. Actually, the dotted-circle still shows for **ALL** Devanagari fonts, and the Roman script is not rendered properly for many of those fonts; eg. in the word "Primer", about 40% of the "e" overlaps the "m".

Is there some way around this?
Does anyone know of a suitable font?... Mono-spaced is preferred.
Or is it something to do with the Ubuntu - gnome-terminal setup?

**Update 2**:
  I tried the same text in `openSUSE (gnome-terminal)`: it failed worse than Ubuntu.
  I tried the same text in `Fedora (Konsole)`: it rendered **PERFECTLY**!
  but that's Fedora, and I'm using Ubuntu :(
  okay, then next obvious step:
  I installed `Konsole` in `Ubuntu`: it rendered **PERFECTLY**!
  but that's Konsole, and I'd rather stay in the gnome family... and Konsle's menu doesn't respond to keyboard... and If Ubuntu+Konsole can do it, then there is probably a way Ubuntu+gnome-terminal can...

**Update 1**:
  As suggeseted, here are some examples.
  The Devanagari looks okay here, but **not** in the termainal (the .png below shows the `Monospace` font)

```
30 - Uncle moon – चंदा मामा/20081119 Hindi Primer part 30 - Uncle moon – चंदा मामा.nag
31 - Rain Queen - वर्षा रानी/20081124 Hindi Primer part 31 - Rain Queen - वर्षा रानी.nag
```

[image]

Actually, **NONE** of the Devanagari-aware fonts render correctly!
...and some of the the Roman script rendering can get pretty whacky.

All entries from the command **$ locale** are set to **"en_AU.UTF-8"**, but even setting everything to **"hi_IN.UTF-8"** makes no difference

Comment: Could you add some real-world sample text in Devanagari script so that people can try out different fonts they may have?

Comment: There's some preliminary work been done on adding devanagari to the Ubuntu font family, so there's a chance this will work better in future: http://design.canonical.com/2010/09/charactersets/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reckon that this is a bug, and is beyond a simple "choose a better font" issue.

The same fonts, including the default **Monospace**, work fine in all other apps I've tried.
and Devanagari fonts doesn't render properly in Fedora's gnome-terminal either,
but the same fonts works in KDE's Konsole **and** also in Konsole running in Ubuntu.

I don't know how to follow a reported and accepted bug, but I found a reference to a gnome-terminal / Devanagari issue (from December of 2008)... and perhaps this is the same issue.

`vte (Ubuntu)`  low (priority)   `Assigned to:` **Ubuntu Desktop Bugs**
https://bugs.launchpad.net/vte/+bug/310053

...and now that I've played with Konsole a bit more, it has revealed some really nice features... especially  **Search Output with Regex**... wow! Just what I wanted...  and the lack of menu-accelerator Keys don't matter, becaue it has fully Kustomizable short-cut Keys... I'm Konverted....  and I've found my **good mono-space font**. It is called **Monospace** :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of GNOME Terminal (VTE) the problem was not the font; the problem was that VTE used to render each cell independently, including a Devanagari spacing combining mark separately from the base letter. This was fixed in VTE version 0.56.

Comment: I am still facing the issue, even with `Google Noto` fonts with gnome-terminal. In GUI everything works fine.