# Hindi Keyboard layout is missing combined characters

Tags: 10.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I am trying to set up a school computer lab with Hindi typing capabilities and am having trouble getting Ubuntu 10.04 to type all of the Hindi combined characters. 
 I'm using "Bolnagri" since it is very intuitive for people who know the English keyboard.  There is a layout document in the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502429)
which shows many combined characters but there are a few characters like `ऋ` which do not have any Third Level Key code mentioned. 
 I found `ॠ` with Character map at `U0960` in the Hindi font but when I type in `ऋ` I get `ॠ`.
Another problem is that `श्र` (zxr) does not work.  It does not combine into the character shown but is a half `श` + `र`. 
 I must be doing something wrong so am hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help, but as far as I know Ubuntu's handling of Devanagari script (and a few others) is not fully implemented yet...

Have a look at this Askubuntu question... [Devanagari script in the Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8437/is-there-a-good-mono-spaced-font-for-devanagari-script-in-the-terminal)

I noticed some problems in the Gnome Terminal, but things work fine in KDE's Konsole Terminal